# how to access data from two tables without foreign key in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

here i have two tables like employee and one mobileoutbox table but these two tables are not connected to each other but i want to access data from two table i want to match data from two table and generate report .how to access data from two table without foreign key?
tables structure :

```
employee table              mobileoutbox table
empid                            srno 
empname                          mobileno
empphoneno                       textmsg
empaddress                       texttype
```

Comment: empphoneno   and mobileno will be same????

Comment: Seems like you are trying to relate two tables that don't have any relations? Can you show sample data, and expected output? I assume that `empphoneno` and `mobileno` might be related, but it would kind of help if you state this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are confusing foreign key constraint with data relationships. Yes, you may have two tables with data match (i.e. these likely phone numbers) and data constraint.

If you need to query both tables relating a column with matching data, just use a INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT employee.*, mobileoutbox.*
FROM employee INNER JOIN mobileoutbox
ON employee.empphoneno = mobileoutbox.mobileno
```

Then you may want to report all the employees, even those who don't have a mobile. In this case, you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to do this:

```
SELECT employee.*, mobileoutbox.*
FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN mobileoutbox
ON employee.empphoneno = mobileoutbox.mobileno
```

This will return all the employees and not null data for the mobileoutbox fields if the employee has a mobile number matching a mobile number in the right table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT em.*, mo.* 
FROM employee em, mobileoutbox mo 
WHERE em.empphoneno = mo.mobileno
```

Tell me if anything is uncertain.

Oh and, if you need to "match" data, then there MUST be a foreign key, some sort of overlapping information between the two tables, i hope you understand that much. I used the phone number in my example as the foreign key, i don't know if that's the reality of the matter.

Comment: This isn't valid SQL in most dialects, let alone SQL Server

Comment: Now you've edited of course it works so don't be clever. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6489476/revisions

Comment: If you were referring to the double equal signs, then yes. Sorry for the sloppy writing. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.empid, e.empname, e.empphoneno, e.empaddress, m.srno, m.mobileno, m.textmsg, m.texttype
FROM employee e, mobileoutbox m
WHERE e.empphoneno = m.mobileno
```

Answer (score 0):

`Union` can do the trick in this case. Just one constraint is you should define the proper columns (one or more) as shown:

```
Select bt.PlayerName from dbo.Batting bt where matchNo = 34 
Union
Select bo.PlayerName from dbo.Bowling bo where matchNo = 34
```